# Highlighting checkboxes and radio buttons using jQuery.

Tags: jquery

I am having some trouble highlighting checkboxes and radio buttons that have been selected. Doing `.css("border", "1px solid red")` or `.css("background-color", "yellow")` doesn't seem to be working.

Other than the default checkmark or filled radio button, I need a way to identify that those checkboxes or radio buttons have been clicked by highlighting it somehow.

HTML examples

```
<input type="radio" title="search" value="T" name="srchType">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="option1">
```

Comment: can you provide your html also??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to retain the browser-default appearance of the checkboxes, there's not too much you can do with css styling. Nonstandard checkbox appearance is not achieved with border or background-color, but with wholesale replacement with new graphics representing the various states (see [here](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) and [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ui-checkbox), for example).

However, depending on how your HTML is structured, you may be able to achieve a pleasing effect with regular css. For example, if have something like this:

```
<label>
<input id="cb1" name="cb1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
My Checkbox
</label>
```

You can apply a style like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').click( function(){
   $(this).parent('label').toggleClass('highlight', this.checked);
});
```

...with css like this:

```
label { display: block; }
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/c3hDK/1/